# Library function is public but deploying automically

Tags: solidity, remix

According to the documentation **If a library has only internal functions then the library is included in the contract that uses it. There is no need to deploy a separate contract for the library.** But I a have public function in a library that's deploying automatically with the contract. But it supposed to be deployed separately cause I was accessing a public function.

Here is my code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.3;

library math{
    function max(uint x, uint y) public pure returns (uint)
        {
            return x >= y ? x : y;
        }
}


contract test{
    function testMax(uint x,uint y) external pure returns (uint) {
        return math.max(x,y);
    }
}
```

Here I can access the max function without deploying the math library. What's the reason behind it?
**Note: I am using remix IDE**

Comment: Perhaps the compiler is smart enough to inline your library code

Comment: I use remix IDE @tsknakamura

Answer (score 2):

This comes down to the compiler that you use. Remix IDE will deploy libraries automatically according to the docs - [see here](https://remix-ide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contract_metadata.html?highlight=library#library-deployment-with-filename-json).

There is an `autoDeployLib` attribute in the artifact JSON file of the calling contract. You can set that to `false` if you'd like to disable this behaviour for a particular contract/library pair. The docs I linked also explain this.

There is also a very similar question I found that might help
[Why can I use Linked Libraries on Remix IDE without deploying them first?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/106574/why-can-i-use-linked-libraries-on-remix-ide-without-deploying-them-first)